# How to select multiple parameters from JSON output, which meets a condition & further select individual value

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq, jsonparser

I have a json output, from which I need to get id value and IPv4_address value where IPv4_address exists (this shouldn't be null). Have to use this ID value for another request along with random generated string.

Here is the breakdown of the requirement :

STEP 1 : 
In the following example, for the ipv4_address:1.1.1.1 & ipv4_address:1.1.1.2, i need to get the id output which is "4e-0365-4e29-95ca-329165eecf8a" and "c9061b6674a8546cea" along with IP address.

Example of my output should look like (something similar):

```
1.1.1.1 4e-0365-4e29-95ca-329165eecf8a
1.1.1.2 c9061b6674a8546cea
```

I was trying to use jq but with this I'm not able to get the both values  :

```
ID="$(echo "$test" \n | jq -r '.USER[] | select(.ipv4_address) | .ipv4_address')"
ID1="$(echo "$test" \n | jq -r '.USER[] | select(.ipv4_address) | .id')"
```

Sample output which is getting displayed with the above 2 commands : 
ID value is : 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2
ID1 value is : 4e-0365-4e29-95ca-329165eecf8a c9061b6674a8546cea

STEP 2: Profile creation: I need to use each $ID1 value in another request along with random generated string.  Random string is generated as per the count of $ID1's (so here I will generate 2 random string)
And thus 2 profiles are created. 
Ques: How can I get each ID from the $ID1 variable ? I tried something like ID1[0] but that seems to be wrong

STEP 3 : 
Will use each ID and random string for another request, Once its done or if that step is failed, i need to provide the output to a file & output should look like :
My requirement for the final output is :

```
1.1.1.1 4e-0365-4e29-95ca-329165eecf8a  <randomvalue-1> <profile-1> DONE
1.1.1.2 c9061b6674a8546cea <randomvalue-2> <profile-2> FAILED
```

where random  value will be generated randomly and shall be used against the ID.

JSON output which needs to be parsed:

```
{
  "errorcode": 0,
  "message": "Done",
  "operation": "get",
  "resourceType": "USER",
  "username": "root",
  "tenant_name": "Owner",
  "tenant_id": "05db6674ad458546cd2",
  "resourceName": "",
  "USER": [
    {
      "is_default": "false",
      "session_timeout": "0",
      "permission": "root",
      "name": "ee",
      "session_timeout_unit": "",
      "tenant_id": "55bcb6674ad45854",
      "id": "4e-0365-4e29-95ca-329165eecf8a",
      "ipv4_address": "1.1.1.1",
      "state": "Up",
      "tenant_name": "Owner",
      "encrypted": "false",
      "groups": [
        "owner"
      ],
      "root_user": ""
    },
    {
      "is_default": "false",
      "session_timeout": "0",
      "permission": "read",
      "name": "test",
      "session_timeout_unit": "",
      "tenant_id": "bc906674ad458546cd2",
      "id": "12cd0-fb7f-4abf-b060-48e98b794b06",
      "tenant_name": "Owner",
      "encrypted": "false",
      "groups": [
        "read"
      ],
      "root_user": ""
    },
    {
      "is_default": "true",
      "session_timeout": "0",
      "permission": "root",
      "name": "root",
      "session_timeout_unit": "",     
      "tenant_id": "c905db6d458546cd2",
      "id": "c9061b6674a8546cea",
      "ipv4_address": "1.1.1.2",
      "state": "Not Reachable",
      "tenant_name": "Owner",
      "encrypted": "false",
      "groups": [
        "owner"
      ],
      "root_user": ""
    },
    {
      "is_default": "false",
      "session_timeout": "0",
      "permission": "readonly",
      "name": "a",
      "session_timeout_unit": "",
      "tenant_id": "c905674ad458546cd2",
      "id": "bc8a-4fd6-bc09-8c39c131b54e",
      "tenant_name": "Owner",
      "encrypted": "false",
      "groups": [
        "read"
      ],
      "root_user": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear with the logic of marking it DONE and FAILED. But to answer your first question where you want to select the multiple fields, you can do something like this:

```
$ cat input.js | jq -r '.USER[] | select(.ipv4_address) | "\(.ipv4_address) \(.id)"' > result.js
```

This will output the result in a file named result.js. You can apply your custom logic of marking DONE and Failed on this file.

In the above command when you do **select(.ipv4_address)** It basically drops all the records for which ipv4_address value is null or it is not present.
if you want to select the records which have ipv4_address as null, then your select statement would become something like this

```
select(.ipv4_address == null)
```

Comment: How to achieve the condition where the output selected must be where ip address has 1.1 and state is up ? I tried this but it ddnt worked : `echo "$output_json" | jq -r '.USER[] | select((.ipv4_address | contains("1.1.") and (.state | contains("UP")))  | "\(.ipv4_address) \(.id)"' > result.js `

Comment: I do not see the state field in the input JSON.

Comment: Have updated the JSON with state. I tried this but couldnt see any output.  `echo "$output_json" | jq -r '.USER[] | select(.ipv4_address | contains("1.1.") and .state=="Up" ) | "\(.ipv4_address) \(.id)"' > result.js `

Comment: The JSON has two missing commas which are making it as invalid JSON. I have corrected them. This is the modified query to meet your requirements. 
`cat input.js | jq  '.USER[] | select(.ipv4_address)' | jq -c 'select(.ipv4_address | contains("1.1"))' | jq 'select(.state == "Up")' `